# If the sum of p, q, r terms of an AP are a, b, c respectively, show that

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic-progressions

If the sum of p, q, r terms of an AP are a, b, c respectively, show that 
$(q-r)$$\frac ap$+$(r-p)$$\frac bq$+$(p-q)$$\frac cr$$=$$0$

Comment: And What's an AP ?

Comment: Arithmetic progression

Comment: Ps if you just paste the question without asking what you actually need help on then other people may mark down your answer as it is unclear in what you are asking just a word of advice. Try to be more specific in what you need help on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i) Let the first term be t, common difference be d

ii) So sum to p terms is: Sp = (p/2)*{2t + (p - 1)d} = a 
So, 2a/p = 2t + pd - d 
==> 2*(a/p)*(q - r) = (2t + pd - d)(q - r) = 2qt - 2rt + pqd - prd - qd + rd ----- (1)

iii) Similarly, 2*(b/q)*(r - p) = 2rt - 2pt + qrd - pqd - rd + pd ----- (2) 
and 2*(c/r)*(p - q) = 2pt - 2qt + prd - qrd - pd + qd ---- (3)

iv) Adding (1), (2) & (3):

2*{(a/p)*(q - r) + (b/q)*(r - p) + (c/r)*(p - q)} = 0

==> (a/p)*(q - r) + (b/q)*(r - p) + (c/r)*(p - q) = 0

Comment: Did you cross multiplied  p/2 with a in the first line and in the 3rd line you multiplied both side with (q-r), am i right.

Comment: where did 2 go from the last line

Comment: If you multiply everything by 2 then 2 is common in everything and so you can just cancel out the 2 by dividing the whole equation by 2.

Comment: And yes you are right (:

Answer (score 0):

> Q:The sum of the first $p, q, r$ terms of an A.P. are $a, b, c$ respectively. Show that
> $$
> \frac{a}{p}(q-r)+\frac{b}{q}(r-p)+\frac{c}{r}(p-q)=0
> $$

Sol. Let $x$ be the first term and $d$ the common difference. Then,
$$
\begin{aligned}
S_{p}=a & \Rightarrow\left(\frac{p}{2}\right) \cdot[2 x+(p-1) d]=a \\
& \Rightarrow \frac{a}{p}=x+(p-1) \cdot \frac{d}{2} \\
& \Rightarrow \frac{a(q-r)}{p}=x(q-r)+(p-1)(q-r) \cdot \frac{d}{2}
\end{aligned}
$$
Similarly,
$$
S_{q}=b \Rightarrow \frac{b(r-p)}{q}=x(r-p)+(q-1)(r-p)-\frac{d}{2}
$$
(ii)
And $S_{r}=c \Rightarrow \frac{c(p-q)}{r}=x(p-q)+(r-1)(p-q) \cdot \frac{d}{2}$
(iii
Adding (i), (ii) and (iii), we get $\frac{a}{p}(q-r)+\frac{b}{q}(r-p)+\frac{c}{r}(p-q)=0$